# Cannot install Apple certificate on Windows IIS

Tags: windows, iis, openssl, certificate

I've been struggling for some hours about how to install a valid certificate on IIS without success.

What I want to achieve is to generate .pkpass files (a passbook file) with a self-made project using a github project called ***dotnet-passbook***. I follow every step described on the github website and one of the author's [links](https://tomasmcguinness.com/2012/06/28/generating-an-apple-ios-certificate-using-windows/) explains how to generate the certificate with IIS but once I've realized them, I add the generated file by Apple using the option called "*Complete certificate request*", it disappears from IIS "Server Certificates" when I reload IIS screen.

I searched about that problem ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21009834/installed-ssl-certificate-in-certificate-store-but-its-not-in-iis-certificate)) and people say that happens when my certificate doesn't contain the private key. I understand this but I don't know how to solve it.

I also searched for an alternative [solution](https://michael-mckenna.com/generating-an-apple-push-notification-certificate-on-windows/) and I used a Win32 OpenSSL to generate the certificate as author explains, but when I'm going to add the final file to IIS, it gives an error called "*Certificate cannot be used as an SSL server certificate*". So I googled about this error but the search gives few results and among them I haven't found any solution.

So, basically these are the things I've tried. I've also tried some other little things, like using "*certutil*" command like explained (entrust.net/knowledge-base/technote.cfm?tn=7905) but nothing.

I'm stucked and I don't know what else to do. If somebody knows how to solve this It'd be awesome. Thank you for any answer.